# Programmatically fix broken Java source code

Tags: java

I'm currently creating a grading utility for my university that compiles, lints, run professor-defined tests, etc. In the process, I'm generating a parse tree of the student's source code so I can do things like check imports, check file structure, check for a minimum number of methods, etc. When generating the parse tree, the file *must* be able to compile (run time errors are a non-factor). The only problem is, not all student submissions actually compile—this is problematic.

Does anyone know of a program that fixes basic Java compilation errors (e.g. missing semi-colons, curly braces, etc.) or of a way that I could go about creating such an application?

I've done some research and the best tool I've found is [walkmod](http://walkmod.com/), but this merely corrects poorly formatted code rather than actually *correcting* the issues.

Comment: @djthoms consider the simple case of an unclosed string. Where and how do you close it programmatically?  `String foo = "this is foo; int bar = 42;` on one line. Well, you close it just before the final `;` and now you've got an error on the next line `System.out.println(foo + bar);` that bar does not exist... and now you try to solve that error? This path leads to madness or JavaScript (they are quite similar).

Comment: @djthoms I am not aware of any such program anyway. You are probably aware of the language complexity of modern programming languages: this is a ridiculously difficult problem to solve in NP. Essentially if an input cannot produce a parse tree, what changes might make it valid without changing its intended meaning? In addition to the complexity, such a program would also need to read minds.

Comment: If that were possible, Java compilers would already do it.

Comment: Let the students submit their code through something that refuses submissions with syntax errors immediately.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich that's something constructive I can actually use. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @djthoms you might have the beginnings of a rather interesting question relating to students submitting via a CI server.

Comment: In fact having the students submitting their code into a repo/CI server with gated check-in would be very good training for the real world.

Comment: @Aron I 100% agree. It's a matter if my univ. will want to go that route or not

Comment: Surely if it doesn't compile you just fail it?

Comment: There are multiple widely-used public-domain tools for checking Java code quality, e.g. checkstyle, findbugs, pmd. All require compilable code. They are highly configurable. You should simply integrate one into your process.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. If a semicolon or curly bracket is missing, it cannot be inserted automatically, since there is no way to know the correct place to insert it. Consider this fragment:

```
if (x) {
doSomething1()
doSomething2()
```

The closing curly bracket is missing, but where would the tool insert it in order to fix the program? In short, compile errors typically indicate *missing information*, and you cannot fix that automatically. (After all, if it was possible to automatically insert say missing semicolons, they you wouldn't need them in the language in the first place.)

(I see this question have been migrated to "software recommendations", but be aware that such a tool cannot exist)

Comment: It is *always* possible to repair a broken program if you allow a large enough patch.  (Joke) Proof:  delete all the text in a file, insert "main(){}" and compile. (There have been a few student-compilers constructed over the years that did a better job of agressive-repair-until-compilable as empirical proof points).  The hard part is not even fixing the syntax; you still have to get the types right.  Still possible.  I'll agree you likely can't repair a student's program and have any hope of executing the student's intent, but you can't prove that because you don't know the student's intent.